# The command ` ls -ltu ` fails to list folders/files based on last accessed time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, gnome

First on your linux desktop create 2 folders.

```
a
b
```

Now run this in the terminal

```
ls -ltu
```

the result is

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 30 20:33 b
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 30 20:33 a
```

Let's click on a and re-run it. 
Same exact result as above.

Let's click on b and re-run it.
 Same exact result as above.

I'm trying to arrange folders based on which one was last clicked on. They recommended `ls -ltu` but it's not working.

Comment: What program is giving the UI to click?  It may be possible that clicking the folder does not cause the program to re-read the directory.  It's also possible that the filesystem is mounted without atime (access time) support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `stat` to see information related to time regarding files & directories.

#### Example

```
$ mkdir a b

$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:08 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:08 b

$ ls -ltu
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:08 a
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:08 b
```

#### Output from stat

Now let's look these directories with the `stat` command:

```
$ stat a b
  File: `a'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643285     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
  File: `b'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643286     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
```

#### Accessing `a`

Now let's access directory `a`:

```
$ ls a
```

Now let's re-check the directories with `stat`:

```
$ stat a b
  File: `a'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643285     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:33.221267791 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
  File: `b'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643286     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
```

We can see that we did indeed effect the directory's stat information with that `ls a`:

*before*

```
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
```

*after*

```
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:33.221267791 -0400
```

#### Accessing `b`

Now if we access the `b` directory, `ls b`:

```
$ ls b

$ ls -ltu
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:17 b
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml saml 4096 Aug 31 00:08 a
```

#### Output from stat

We can see that the access time has changed and the output above from the `ls -ltu` is as it should be:

```
$ stat a b
  File: `a'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643285     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:33.221267791 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
  File: `b'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 5643286     Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-08-31 00:17:15.279776957 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
Change: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
```

We can again see that a simple `ls b` caused the access time to get updated:

*before*

```
Access: 2013-08-31 00:08:03.621936538 -0400
```

*after*

```
Access: 2013-08-31 00:17:15.279776957 -0400
```

#### Summary

In looking at the above analysis I don't see any reason why `ls -ltu` would not show you the directories sorted by their access times as expected.

#### So what's up?

Perhaps you have the directory mounted such that access times are not being tracked? This would explain why there is no change.

If you look in the man page for the mount command you'll see these 2 options defined:

```
atime     Update inode access time for each access. See also the 
          strictatime mount option.

noatime   Do not update inode access times on this filesystem (e.g, 
          for faster access on the news spool to speed up news servers).
```

You can check how your filesystem is mounted using the `mount` command. If a device is mounted such that the option `noatime` shows up, then it's being mounted so that access time (atime) is not being tracked. This is done typically to increase performance.

#### Example

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda5 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_grinchy-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/saml/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=saml)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is exactly what you need:

```
ls -Aru | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Why do you believe that this will give better results that what the user has already tried?