# Access time is not being updated when i run ` ls a ` and then ` stat a`

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

On CentOS Linux desktop let's create a folder named `a`.

```
mkdir a
```

Then let's access it

```
ls a
```

and then let's get it's statistics

```
stat a

  File: `a'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 1183593     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-30 21:35:55.089404752 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-30 21:35:54.077415503 -0400
Change: 2013-08-30 21:35:54.077415503 -0400
```

Okay let's access it again

```
ls a
```

and get it's access time again

```
stat a

  File: `a'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 1183593     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-08-30 21:35:55.089404752 -0400
Modify: 2013-08-30 21:35:54.077415503 -0400
Change: 2013-08-30 21:35:54.077415503 -0400
```

As you can see there is no difference between the "ACCESS" times.

Here are two access times right next to each other.

```
Access: 2013-08-30 21:35:55.089404752 -0400
Access: 2013-08-30 21:35:55.089404752 -0400
```

They look absolutely identical! What can i do about this? I'm simply using CentOS Linux desktop, which uses GNOME by default.

Comment: What does the command `mount` show?

Comment: Please see the bottom of my answer to your previous Q. It covers how to see if access time is not getting handled correctly: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88952/the-command-ls-ltu-fails-to-list-folders-files-based-on-last-accessed-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could occur for a couple of reasons:

- First, if the filesystem is mounted with `atime` disabled, that would prevent it from updating on `ls`.
- Second, if the filesystem does not support `atime`, that would lead to the same result.